# QML Android Image cannot open Internal file even if exists

Tags: android, qt, permissions, storage, internal

I have a problem on displaying image files, which are stored on in Internal Storage, on QML Image item. I tried many things but could not figure it out how can I achieve it. Any help appreciated.

QML Side:

```
Image {
                id: userPhotoDrawer;
                anchors.centerIn: parent;
                width   : Math.min(parent.width , parent.height);
                height  : width;
                sourceSize: Qt.size(width , height);
                source: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/share_example_x_files/qt-logo.png"
            }

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent;
                onClicked: Caminho.buscaImagem();
            }


            Connections
            {
                target: Caminho;
                onImagemCaminhoChanged:
                {
                    var path = Caminho.imagemCaminho;
                    Caminho.checkPath(path);
                }
            }

        }
```

In caminhoImagens.cpp:

```
QString caminhoImagens::checkPath(QString pPath)
{
QFile tFile(pPath);
QStringList tList = pPath.split("/");
QString fileName = tList.last();
QString header = pPath.split(fileName).first();

QDir tdir(header);
if (tdir.exists())
{
    qDebug() << "absolute path : " << tdir.absoluteFilePath(fileName)
             << endl << "file exists : " << tFile.exists();
}
return QUrl::fromLocalFile(pPath).toString();}
```

Explanation, I'm using image picker to set user photo in my application. I got path correct according to above function outputs. For instance,
**file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/share_example_x_files/qt-logo.png**

I also tried to set **source** by:
source: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/share_example_x_files/qt-logo.png

Nothing changed. The output still : **: QML Image: Cannot open: file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/share_example_x_files/qt-logo.png**

I also added following permissions under my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank your for help

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution by digging QFile::errorString after trying to copy the file into another place. The error was permission denied!

After I searched why I got this error even if I have required permission on my manifest file, I found that after KitKat, Android wants granting permission from user on application. Therefore before selecting Image I put request permission function into my QML.

```
   MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent;
                onClicked:
                {
                    if (PermissionManager.requestPermissions())
                        Caminho.buscaImagem();
                }

            }
```

And the related cpp code:

```
bool QAndroidPermissions::requestPermissions()
```

{

```
QtAndroid::PermissionResult r = QtAndroid::checkPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
if(r == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied) {
    QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync( QStringList() << "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" );
    r = QtAndroid::checkPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    if(r == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;}
```

Comment: saved my day after spending 12 hours to solve the problem